# How to Store the JsonData into the Array Wheel Adepter

Tags: android, json, sorting

Hi Guys I am new in android and i want to know how to sort the data which is come from    Json String.
Here Is the Code of Getting the Key and Value of the Json and Stored it in Wheel      Adapter.It Display the data in WheelAdapter But not in Ascending Order.

```
MainActivity.java
-------------------

    JSONObject jObject;
    String stradptr[];
    private boolean wheelScrolled = false;
    ArrayWheelAdapter<String> adapter;

    try {

            String str = getResponseText("http://www.credit-direct.be/Application/Webservice/GetRates.php?type=PAT");

            jObject = new JSONObject(str);
            Log.i("TRY", "COMMING");
            Iterator iter = jObject.keys();
            stradptr = new String[20];
            Log.i("ITRETER", "COMMING");
            int i = 0;
            while (iter.hasNext()) {

                String key = (String) iter.next();
                String value = jObject.getString(key);

                stradptr[i++] = key + " mois - " + value;
                Log.v(key, value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

               wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.wheelView1);
               initWheel1(R.id.wheelView1);
    }

     // initWheel1 Method...


               private void initWheel1(int id) {
        WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
        adapter = new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                stradptr);

        // Arrays.sort(stradptr);

        adapter.setTextSize(20);
        wheel.setViewAdapter(adapter);

        wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
        wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
        wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    }
```

Comment: what issue u are getting with current code?

Comment: I am Getting the Data unsorted but i want it to be sorted..In Url the data is in ascending order but in my code it is not in any order.

Comment: have you tried `Arrays.sort(stradptr)` before passing Array to adapter constructor ?

Comment: Yes sir i tried it and also i tried this one..            Map<String, String> unsortMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    unsortMap.put(key, value);
   
    Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(unsortMap);
    Log.v(key, value);

Comment: then try it after changing String stradptr[]; to `double stradptr[]` for this you will need to parse values from JSon string to double before adding to double array. and then call `Arrays.sort(stradptr)` on double array instead of string

Comment: Ok I will try this but is there any other solution to sorting the string array which is display in my code?

Comment: Its not working because in wheel adapter use like this " key+ " mois - " + value; example of this "48 mois - 9.95" whis is string so i am using here the stringAdapter. And the further calculation is done with this..

Comment: then use `key+ " mois - " +String.valueOf(value);` for showing value in wheel Adapter

Comment: Then how should i do?? Like this..   double stradptr[];stradptr=new double[20];int i = 0;
   while (iter.hasNext()) {

    //String key = (String) iter.next();

    //double key=(Double) iter.next();
    double value=jObject.getDouble(key);

Comment: But its not working bcz in iteratior it can't get the double value..it accept string

Comment: or i can use like this.....double key=(Double) iter.next();
    double value=jObject.getDouble(key); but it defines the error like The method getDouble(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (double) so Change type of key to string..

Comment: double org.json.JSONObject.getDouble(String name) throws JSONException

Comment: i want to set the Key to be sorted u check the following link "http://www.credit-direct.be/Application/Webservice/GetRates.php?type=PAT" The key is in ascending order like 24,30,36,42 and so on...and according to that the value are changes...But the line jObject.getDouble(key); it fire error like key is not a string so type cast it..and in the initWheel1(), I declare the adapter = new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
    stradptr);
Which takes String only.

Comment: have you tried it as  http://pastebin.com/CVFVDXHu ?

Comment: Ya i tried but there is not any of the effect..:(

Comment: @varshaBhatia  how u resolved your issue ?